# Snapshot.exists() false negative on network error

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problem handling network connection problems with the snapshot listener as it checks if doc.exists === false creates a new one.

```
    onSnapshot(this.userDocRef, {
          next: (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
              const data = snapshotFactory(snapshot);
              console.log("data recieved from firestore: ", data);
              this.user.value = UserStore.firebaseUser
                ? userFactory(data, UserStore.firebaseUser)
                : null;
            } else { 
              console.log("document doesnt exist, creating one...");              
              let userData = {
                id: firebaseUser.uid,
                email: firebaseUser.email || "error:firebaseUser-no-email",
                displayName: firebaseUser.displayName || null,
                photoURL: firebaseUser.photoURL || null,
                emailVerified: firebaseUser.emailVerified,
                createdAt: new Date(),
              };
              setDoc(this.userDocRef!, userData);
            }
```

When having bad internet connection 'snapshot.exists()' returns false and creates a new document overwriting the current document when connection is back.

It can be reproduced blocking request to firestore.googleapis.com.

How can i detect if snapshot really exists or if has been an internet connection problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `snapshot` is a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot), which has a `metadata` property with information about the status of the snapshot. You'll want to check if [`fromCache`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.snapshotmetadata.md#snapshotmetadatafromcache) is true, as in that case the snapshot may not be up to date with the status on the server.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I managed to avoid this problem with your advice. I know tha this is an edge case where connection is available for auth to be ready but not to contact firestore but I didnt want to risk loosing user data.